# Take array value and separate from the rest

Tags: php, laravel

I am querying from eloquent and receiving records in an array, I need to get each value of the team that is in the records to validate if it is larger or smaller than the value entered in the form.

```
public function listarLojasParaValidarInsercaoHorarioLoja(string $uuidLoja,array $dados) : string
{

    $loja = $this->getByLoja($uuidLoja);
    $idLoja = $loja[0]->getLoja()->getId();

    $diaSemana = $dados['dia_semana'];


    $bancoHorario = HorarioLojaLaravel::where('loja_id', '=', $idLoja)
                        ->where('dia_semana', '=', $diaSemana)->get();
    $contarBanco = $bancoHorario->count();

    if ($contarBanco > 0) {
        $aberturaBanco = HorarioLojaLaravel::where('loja_id', '=', $idLoja)
                            ->where('dia_semana', '=', $diaSemana)
                            ->get('horario_abertura');

        $fechamentoBanco = HorarioLojaLaravel::where('loja_id', '=', $idLoja)
                               ->where('dia_semana', '=', $diaSemana)
                               ->get('horario_fechamento');

        foreach ($aberturaBanco as $key => $value) {

            $horario_abertura = $dados['horario_abertura'];
            $horario_fechamento = $dados['horario_fechamento'];

            if ($horario_abertura >= $aberturaBanco and $horario_abertura <= $fechamentoBanco || $horario_fechamento <= $fechamentoBanco and $horario_fechamento >= $horario_abertura) {
                echo $aberturaBanco;
            } else {
                echo $aberturaBanco;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return False;
    }
}
```

Result var_dump()

```
[{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"}][{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"}][{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"}][{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"}][{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"},{"horario_abertura":"09:00:00"}]
```

I need to get the numbers

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but check the `if ($horario_abertura >= $aberturaBanco...` part. You may need to add some parentheses to get the ands and ors to interact the way you intend them to.

Comment: I need $aberturaBanco to become only the values of the array horario_abertura which would be 08:00:00

Comment: @RichardNicson do you want `$aberturaBanco = [08:00:00", "08:00:00", "08:00:00","09:00:00"...` ?

Comment: Yes , but I need to be one at a time to validate with $ horario_abertura

Comment: @RichardNicson use `$value` instead of `$aberturaBanco` on your `if` condition inside `foreach`

Comment: @Hafez only value give it back to me {"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"}, I need you to return only 08:00:00

Comment: echo $value = result {"horario_abertura":"08:00:00"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed what you need according to your comments, replace `->get('horario_abertura')` to `->pluck('horario_abertura')` on your code:

```php
$aberturaBanco = HorarioLojaLaravel::where('loja_id', '=', $idLoja)
                        ->where('dia_semana', '=', $diaSemana)
                        ->pluck('horario_abertura');
```

and change your foreach to this:

```php
foreach ($aberturaBanco as $key => $value) {

            $horario_abertura = $dados['horario_abertura'];
            $horario_fechamento = $dados['horario_fechamento'];

            if ($horario_abertura >= $value and $horario_abertura <= $fechamentoBanco || $horario_fechamento <= $fechamentoBanco and $horario_fechamento >= $horario_abertura) {
                echo $value;
            } else {
                echo $value;
            }
        }
```

Another simpler solution is to change nothing and use `$value['horario_abertura']` to get the value you want.

Please tell me if it solves your issue.

Comment: Error: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: "codigo_status_http": 500,
  "codigo_erro_zcrm": "500",
  "mensagem": "stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given",
  "linha": 1061,
  "stack": "#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'stripos() expec...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1061, Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php(1061):

Comment: at the time you change get to value you raise this error.

Comment: @RichardNicson can you please try `pluck` instead of `value` and tell me the results

Comment: ["08:00:00","08:00:00","08:00:00","09:00:00","09:00:00"]  take one at a time

Comment: @RichardNicson you can get one ate a time on your `foreach`

Comment: How to use fechamentoBanco and aberturaBanco in foreach?

Comment: $horario = array_combine($aberturaBanco, $fechamentoBanco);

                        foreach($horario as $key => $value) {